# How to create a views grid display with "promoted regions" inside?

Tags: views

I need to create a grid view with a special display. The view is a normal grid of nodes obeying the filters set up for this view.

However, there are 2 promoted spots on the grid that display items with a different size.

[image]

These items need to be chosen by the administrator of the site.
I was thinking using a node queue for this purpose, but I'm not sure how to create the display to integrate it inside.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: I think this won't work with a grid view, because it's a table. I have no idea how to break up the table markup to come up with something like the above. I'd rather go with an unformatted list, then apply a class to the promoted nodes and try to "float" them via css or alternatively use masonry (http://drupal.org/project/masonry)...

Comment: I agree for the table, I kept the grid term more for semantics ;). I also thought using masonry or CSS but I'm not sure how to float these items in the correct position. Also the problem of inserting these items in the view still remains.

Comment: Is the position of the featured content always the same or changing?

Comment: It's always the same.

Comment: I desagree about the table option: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html If you take a look in the lower part of this page, you come up with the solution. The <tr> and <td> supports  atrributes called _colspan_ and _rawspan_ whose aim goal is the creation of different cells. If the format is static , you can build a template in a few minutes, but it's a dynamic format, you would need time, a little of modular arithmetic and build a logic in a prepreccess hook. On the other hand, if you feel more confindece with a list, it`s also a good idea.

Comment: I agree that `rowspan` and `colspan` would help generate such table but the problem is how can I fit a view inside such a layout and also how can I put the 2 promoted nodes in their respective spot ?